# Forming 4 groups from 16 people

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many ways can $16$ students split up into $4$ study groups of size $4$ if (i) each group studies a different topic? (ii) all groups study the same topic?

My Idea : (i) Since with respect to topics we can form groups we see for the first topic there are $\binom{16}{4}$ ways next there are $\binom{12}{4}$ ways and next there are $\binom{8}{4}$ ways and the last $4$ gets fixed. So in total there are $\binom{16}{4}\binom{12}{4}\binom{8}{4}$ ways to form the scenario.

(ii) This will have the same ans as (i), since essentially we are forming groups.

Is my idea correct? Or we need to consider the $4!$ term in the first part for permuting topics after forming groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. The difference between (i) and (ii) is that the order of the four groups no longer matters (since they are all studying the same topic), so you need to divide by another 4!.  Hence the answer to (ii) is $\dfrac{\binom{16}{4}\binom{12}{4}\binom{8}{4}}{4!}$.

Comment: I thought forming only groups means they are distinct and for distinct elements, order matters. Doesn't it?

Comment: @mudok It's more of a language exercise than a mathematics exercise to tell the difference, and the only way to learn is to read and solve a lot of exercises and keep deciphering whatever the author actually means. In case ii), the only thing that matters is who is in group with whom. There is no "group 1, group 2" and so on. It is only "Albert's group, Brittany's group" and so on (except Albert and Brittany may be in the same group, so it doesn't work so nicely for listing all possible group configurations).

Comment: @Arthur I can feel the same about the meaning you gave. And according to that the number of such instances must be less than the first (i) since there both things(topic + who is  with who) matter. I still dont understand why its divided by $4!$.

Comment: @mudok Here's a simpler scenario that makes it clearer.  Suppose we have four people: A, B, C, D.  We want to put them in two groups of two.  If we do 4C2 = 6 then that counts (AB) (CD) and (CD) (AB) as two different scenarios, while they should actually be counted as the same; that's why we divide by 2! to get 3 ways (the ways are (AB) (CD), (AC) (BD), (AD) (BC)).  Similarly in this scenario we have to divide by 4! since each arrangement is overcounted 4! times by rearranging the groups.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just to think about it the other way:

The number of permutation between 16 people is 16!. The number of permutations inside a group is 4!.
But we are not interested in permutation inside groups, so divide the whole number of permutations by permutations for each group.

which is multinomial coefficient

$\frac{16!}{4!\cdot4!\cdot4!\cdot4!}$

for (i), and divide by 4! permutations of groups themselves to get (ii) as stated above

Comment: This is close, but is off by a factor of $4!$; can you see why?